# How to interpret rsync console output?

Tags: rsync

I use the following rsync command to backup my files:

```
rsync -avHc Pictures /backup/
```

Isn't `-v` supposed to only display files and directories that were transferred? If I change a file and run the above command twice (without changing the Pictures directory), shouldn't only the first pass output the changed file/directory?

Comment: Can you extend the question with filesystem information of the partitions of the `Pictures` and `/backup/` directory (only one if they are both on the same partition, but please indicate so). I suspect the problem maybe caused by the `/backup/` being on a VFAT formatted partition.

Comment: Source is ext4 (my System SSD) and destination is NTFS (my external Backup HDD)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the `-v` option should only list the transferred files/directories. Are there any applications running that might change the Pictures folder?

Maybe you can try this:

```
mkdir /backup/Pictures
rsync -avHc Pictures/ /backup/Pictures
```

Did it make any difference? Maybe try after the first run `diff /backup Pictures`, what's the output there?

Comment: Hi and thanks, I kept experimenting a bit. I found out about the --delete option which solved the problem of automatically purged old logs and so on.